# Google Analytics XML Config File vs JSON?

Tags: android, json, xml, google-analytics

I've added Google Analytics to my mobile application by using the `google-services.json` file.

Now I've enabled **auto activity tracking** and I want to provide a screen name for each activity.

Google documents say, I should add

```
<screenName name=".MyActivity">My activity</screenName>
```

to my **XML configuration file**. Where's this coming from? I don't have a xml config file, I have a `google-services.json` file.

Do I need to create a XML file inside res/xml/ ? 
What values are necessary as I am currently using the android default `R.xml.global_tracker` ?

Or do I need to add these screen-name information to the json file and if yes, whats the structure then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own XML. Here is mine, remember to replace your tracking ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-99999999-1</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.SettingsActivity">SettingsActivity</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.BreakActivity">BreakActivity</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.FinishedActivity">FinishedActivity</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.InitialActivity">InitialActivity</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.codylab.squats.WorkoutActivity">WorkoutActivity</screenName>

</resources>
```

Create an Application class:

```
public class YourNameApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        analytics.newTracker(R.xml.squats_tracker);
    }
}
```

Add a name attribute of application tag in your AndroidMenifest.xml

```
...

<application
    android:name=".YourNameApplication"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```